# Spring Boot SSL and keystore certificate installation

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-boot, ssl-certificate

I have issues configuring the spring boot tomcat SSL to work with Comodo EV certificate. This is however my first time doing this so obviously I am making some stupid mistake somewhere. Any help would be MUCH appreciated since I'm already struggling with this for days...

So, my scenario is as follows:

- Spring Boot, Java 8.
- I created KeyStore2.jks, created CSR and sent it to Comodo. I also exported the private key for just in case I mess something (I hope it is possible to import a private key to a new keystore in case I mess the entire keystore..)
- Comodo issued the certificate and send 4 files over:

  1.Root CA Certificate - AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
  2.Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
  3.Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSAExtendedValidationSecureServerCA.crt
  4.POSITIVE EV SSL Certificate - mydomain_com.crt

Following their instructions, I have imported all 4 into my keystore:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file  AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt -keystore KeyStore2.jks 
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate -file COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt -keystore KeyStore2.jks 
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate2 -file COMODORSAExtendedValidationSecureServerCA.crt -keystore KeyStore2.jks 
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias domain -file mydomain_com.crt -keystore KeyStore2.jks
```

However, after importing root, I got a warning:

```
Certificate already exists in system-wide CA keystore under alias <addtrustexternalca>
Do you still want to add it to your own keystore? [no]:  yes
```

I moved the KeyStore2.jks to /src/main/resources in Spring Boot project.

My Spring Boot application.properties config:

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:KeyStore2.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=mykeystorepass
server.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS
server.ssl.keyAlias=domain
server.ssl.key-password=mykeypass
```

And then here we go :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: Alias name [domain] does not identify a key entry
```

I'm now trying everything using the trial-and-error method but nothing.
If I comment out the last two lines in .properties:

```
server.ssl.keyAlias=domain
server.ssl.key-password=mykeypass
```

The tomcat responds with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.security.KeyStoreException: Cannot store non-PrivateKeys
```

If I list the entries in my keystore using keytool -list, that's the output (fingerprints omitted):

```
root, Mar 10, 2018, trustedCertEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):...
domain, Mar 10, 2018, trustedCertEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): .....
intermediate, Mar 10, 2018, trustedCertEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): ....
intermediate2, Mar 10, 2018, trustedCertEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): ...
```

Is it possible that cert is not aligned with a private key or something?

How to check that?

Does alias naming have any functional meaning?

Does it matter whether I use JKS or PKCS12 keystore format for Spring Boot?

That's my first time installing the external cert. I did it many times with self-signed certs without any issues but this one... please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you don't have a PrivateKeyEntry in your keystore. All the certificates are added as trustedCertEntry. This means that the certificates are there, and would be trusted should you use this keystore as a truststore, but your domain certificates private key is not properly added along with the certificate.

As far as I'm aware, keytool cannot do this, but you can use openssl instead with this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my_domain.crt -inkey my_domain_key.key -out keystore.p12
```

This will create a PKCS12 keystore with your domain certificate as a PrivateKeyEntry.

After that you can use keytool as usual to add the other certificates, though I don't think you should need the root certificate.

Out of curiousity, how did you do it for self signed certs? This would have been an issue for those as well.

Another issue I have run into from time to time is that the application can't read the private key. This has always been caused by the keystore and the key itself having different passwords. I see that you have specifically configured the key password so this might not be an issue for you (I didn't know you could do that).

Alias naming is not important as long as aliases are unique within the keystore.

PKCS12 is recommended (even by keytool itself). PKCS12 is an open standard while JKS is Java standard.

To verify that the keystore is correctly setup, list the contents as before. It should say something like this (copied and modified manually):

```
root, Mar 10, 2018, trustedCertEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):...
domain, Mar 10, 2018, PrivateKeyEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): .....
intermediate, Mar 10, 2018, trustedCertEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): ....
intermediate2, Mar 10, 2018, trustedCertEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): ..
```

Disclaimer: I'm self taught on the subject, very recently too, so I'm no expert.